# How can I "mount" a file into a directory in a docker container using docker-py?

Tags: docker, dockerpy

I need to get a single file from my host machine into a per-existing directory in a docker container using [`docker-py`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). The directory shall not be overridden means `mount` is no option. Moving the directory to allow a shared `volume` between the host and the container is no option as well.

Comment: Have you tried mounting file, not directory? When you mount with `--volume` full path including filename and extension, it shouldn't overwrite directory.

Comment: Yeah, but probably I just mixed up the arguments...

Comment: Seems like it works to mount a folder from the host into the container without overriding the parent directory with `client.containers.run(image='ubuntu', name='ubuntu', volumes={'/tmp/folder': {'bind': '/tmp/folder', 'mode': 'ro'}}, network='host', command='ls /tmp')`...

Comment: @AlexGalera Thx. Works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single file on the host `/tmp/hostfile.txt` can be mounted into a container `/tmp/containerfile.txt` e.g. via pseudo code:

```py
import docker

client = docker.from_env()
stdout = client.containers.run(
    image='ubuntu',
    name='ubuntu',
    volumes={
        '/tmp/container.txt': {
            'bind': '/tmp/hostfile.txt',
            'mode': 'ro',
        }
    },
    network='host',
    command='ls /tmp',
)
```

(The string `stdout` contains the `file.txt`.)